# jquery/php incremental search iterate thru results with previous and next buttons

Tags: php, jquery, search, live, loops

I'm looking to do an incremental search within a specific section on a page. I'm currently using the 'Live Search with Quicksilver Style' plugin to handle search results:

http://static.railstips.org/orderedlist/demos/quicksilverjs/

If I type "the" in the search box, results are altered where the text "the" is part of the results. Now I would like to add the option to cycle thru all iterations of the word "the" where it appears within the search results. I looked at the .prev() and .next() option found here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/31/50-jquery-function-demos-for-aspiring-web-developers/

But I'm not sure how to implement it into the scenario described above.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks